# Magento 1.9 new admin user current password

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, admin-user

I've installed fresh 1.9 CE Magento providing an admin user and password. I can login to backend, but when I want to create new user for admin access, there is a 'current admin password' and I cannot create new user because the new user has not current password and this field is mandatory. How can I create a new admin user?
What I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the *current admin password* of the user you are logged in with, not the one you are about to create.

Comment: Thank you! logical, but I had not thought about it